# $\det(I+A) = 1 + tr(A) + \det(A)$ for $n=2$ and for $n>2$?

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let $I$ the identity matrix and $A$ another general square matrix. In the case $n=2$ one can easily  verifies that
\begin{equation}
\det(I+A) = 1 + tr(A) + \det(A)
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\det(I+tA) = 1 +  t\  tr(A) + t^2\det(A)
\end{equation}
for some scalar $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

I have tried to see if there exists a similar formula for $n>3$. This is a natural question. But the calculations are very big and difficulty to see. Then I do the answer. Is there a similar formula for $n>2$?

Comment: Are you looking for this formula : $\det(I+tA) = \sum_{k=0}^n t^k \operatorname{Tr}(\Lambda^{k} A)$ ? (cf [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial)).

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} \det(I+tA)=Tr(A)$ so perhaps we can think of this as the integral form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\left|
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    1+a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
    a_{21} & 1+a_{22} & a_{23} \\
    a_{31} & a_{32} & 1+a_{33} \\
  \end{array}
\right|
=
\left|
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
    0 & 1+a_{22} & a_{23} \\
    0 & a_{32} & 1+a_{33} \\
  \end{array}
\right|
+
\left|
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
    a_{21} & 1+a_{22} & a_{23} \\
    a_{31} & a_{32} & 1+a_{33} \\
  \end{array}
\right|=
$$
$$
=
\left|
  \begin{array}{cc}
    1+a_{22} & a_{23} \\
    a_{32} & 1+a_{33} \\
  \end{array}
\right|
+
\left|
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    a_{11} & 0 & a_{13} \\
    a_{21} & 1  & a_{23} \\
    a_{31} & 0 & 1+a_{33} \\
  \end{array}
\right|
+
\left|
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
    a_{31} & a_{32} & 1+a_{33} \\
  \end{array}
\right|
=\ldots
$$
$$
=
1+{\rm tr}A + M_{11} + M_{22} + M_{33}+\det A
$$
and further by induction.

Answer (score 23):

If $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ then the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is 
$$
\det(tI-A)=(t-a_1)(t-a_2)\cdots(t-a_n).$$ 
Therefore

- $\det(I+A)=(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\cdots(1+a_n) = 1 + \operatorname{tr}A+ \ldots + \det A$

and

- $\det(I+tA)=(1+ta_1)(1+ta_2)\cdots(1+ta_n)= 1 + t\operatorname{tr}A+ \ldots + t^n\det A$.

Answer (score 15):

One can formally expand $\det(I+tA)$ as a power series of $t$ and get:

$$\begin{align}
  & \det(I + tA)\\
= & \exp\left(\text{Tr}\log(I+tA)\right)\\
= & \exp\left(t\,\text{Tr}A - \frac{t^2}{2}\text{Tr}A^2 + \frac{t^3}{3}\text{Tr}A^3 + \cdots
\right)\\
= & 1 + t\,\text{Tr}A + \frac{t^2}{2!}\left( (\text{Tr}A)^2 - \text{Tr}A^2 \right)
+ \frac{t^3}{3!}\left((\text{Tr}A)^3 - 3 (\text{Tr}A)(\text{Tr}A^2) + 2 \text{Tr}A^3 \right)
+ \cdots
\end{align}$$

When $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix, the above expansion terminate at the $t^n$ term with coefficient equal to $\det A$. With this, you can obtain formula similar to what you have for $n = 2$:

$$
\det(I+tA) = \begin{cases}
1 + t\,\text{Tr}A + t^2 \det(A) & n = 2\\
\\
1 + t\,\text{Tr}A + \frac{t^2}{2!}\left( (\text{Tr}A)^2 - \text{Tr}A^2 \right) + t^3 \det(A) & n = 3\\
\\
1 + t\,\text{Tr}A + \frac{t^2}{2!}\left( (\text{Tr}A)^2 - \text{Tr}A^2 \right)
\\\;\;\;+ \frac{t^3}{3!}\left((\text{Tr}A)^3 - 3 (\text{Tr}A)(\text{Tr}A^2) + 2 \text{Tr}A^3 \right)
+ t^4 \det(A) & n = 4\\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: how do you obtain $\text{det(I+tA)}=\text{exp(Tr log(I+tA))}?$

Comment: @vidyarthi any matrix $A$ with complex coefficients is similar to one in Jordan normal form. It is easy to verify the expression when $A$ is in jordon normal form. Since both $\exp$ and $\log$ is compatible with similarity transform ( i.e $\exp(SAS^{-1}) = S\exp(A)S^{-1}$, $\log(SAS^{-1}) = S\log(A)S^{-1}$ ), the expression works generally.

Answer (score 2):

Continuation of P.'s answer:

$\det(I+tA)=(1+ta_1)(1+ta_2)\cdots(1+ta_n)=1+e_1t+e_2t^2+\cdots e_nt^n$
where $e_i$s are elementary symmetric polynomials of $a_i$s, eigenvalues. By inverse Newton-Girard identities, we have
$$e_1=Tr A$$
$$e_2=\frac{p_1e_1-p_2}{2}=\frac{(TrA)^2-TrA^2}{2}$$
$$e_3=\frac{p_1e_2-p_2e_1+p_3}{3}=\frac{(TrA)^3-3TrA\,TrA^2+2TrA^3}{6}$$
$$e_4=\frac{p_1e_3-p_2e_2+p_3e_1-p_4}{4}=\frac{(TrA)^4-6(TrA)^2TrA^2+8TrA\,TrA^3+3(TrA^2)^2-6TrA^4}{24}$$
$$...$$
where $p_i$s are power sums.