# If $M$ is $n$ by $n$ square matrix, and $\det(M+I) \ge 0$, show that $\det(M^5+I) \ge 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> If $M$ is $n$ by $n$ square matrix and $$\det(M+I) \ge 0$$ show that $$\det(M^5+I) \ge 0$$

I was trying with eigenvalues but I got stuck.

Comment: $M^5+I=(M+I)(M^4-M^3+M^2-M+I)$

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya and how to show that the det of second factor $\ge 0$?

Comment: Maybe you could construct a matrix from the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: See this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/457249/721644

Answer (score 2):

*Hints.*

- If $\det(M+I)$ is zero, $\det(M^5+I)$ must be zero too because $M+I$ is a factor of the polynomial $M^5+I$.
- If $\det(M+I)>0$, the number of real eigenvalues of $M$ that are smaller than $-1$ must be even.